# Linux: Visualize writes to a file

Tags: linux, kernel

I am looking for a way to visualize writes to a big file (2GB) in real-time. The writing process isn't just appending data to the end of the file. Instead, it acts like a container or like a block device. So data is written anywhere within the file.

Is there a tool that shows me which parts of the file are changing? It does not need to be precise - in fact - I just need to know wheter it's at the beginning, in the middle or end of the file. Best would be a tool that works on the CLI.

I was unable to find such a tool, but maybe someone here can help.

Answer (score 5):

[Seekwatcher](http://oss.oracle.com/~mason/seekwatcher/) uses `blktrace` underneath and can provide you all kinds of information about disk activity. It can analyze existing blktrace dump files or start blktrace for you. Seekwatcher is probably not *exactly* what you are looking for, but maybe it can serve as a starting point.

Also look for blktrace analyzers, perhaps there are others lurking somewhere out there. +1 for interesting question, anyway!